# NGX Perfect Scrollbar: Remove horizontal scroll in IE11 while decreasing scale

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, perfect-scrollbar

The issue was reproduced on IE11. Horizontal scroll axis appeared when I decreased scale. I tried to use `suppressScrollX: true` and `useBothWheelAxes: false` but it doesn't work.

How can I remove x axis on IE11 while scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that works for me. However, using of `suppressScrollX: true` and `useBothWheelAxes: false` doesn't work, I removed x axis via CSS:

```
::ng-deep .ps--active-x > .ps__rail-x {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have solved this problem. Congratulations! If you have any further question, it is better to post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).